# Quasar line break is printing as <br /> isntead of line break

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

`return str + '<br />' + data`
I am trying to print this in quasar, but its printing 
 as a text instead of line. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `v-html` directive

```
<div v-html="html"></div>
```

Here html can be returned raw HTML string.

Refer this for more information:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html